# It is possible to avoid Android to close a non visible activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity non visible, with some variables that must be accesed by static way. This activity can't be a service, because it is a MapView activity.

I need to access some static varibales of the activity anytime. I know that  Android can close suspended activities (non visible activities) so.... how can i avoid it? i need that my suspended non visible activitity never get's deleted by Android.

The variable that i need to access staticly is a the own MapActivity instance variable because i need to pass it to another mapView objects from other activities

```
public class OsmMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    public static OsmMapActivity instance;      
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = new View(this);
        setContentView(v);
        instance=this;
```

Comment: hmm,intresting ,never done so, but just a thought,from onDestroy of that call that activity again. OR from onPause call onResume again...don't know these is right Question or is this a Right way to use Android activity.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What does "SO" mean?

Comment: If the data is static then it doesn't depend of a current activity object being alive.

Comment: Aromero, are you sure about it? if i have a reference to a variable created on a deleted activity (deleted by android), the variable is still alive? The variable es a MapActivity instance variable......

Comment: So you are holding a MapActivity instance in a static field of the MapActivity itself? Can I ask why? There is something wrong with your approach.

Comment: i am holding it because i need to access it by other activities and use that variable in some MapView objects. It is a hard need for a "special" huge app

Comment: Then, the variable will be deleted or will be alive?

Comment: Store your data somewhere else, if it's something transient you can use your Application object (is a singleton) to store it.

Comment: @AndroidUser99 the object will be alive since you are holding a reference to it. But again, this is surely NOT the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many variables do you have? I would create a singleton and manage those with maybe SharedSettings. You can create a POJO and save it.

Also, you could make an object, implement Parcelable interface and pass it to the Activity where you need the information.

Comment: it is a MapActivity instance variable

Comment: Why are you doing it that way? What exactly are you using your instance for?

Comment: i am holding it because i need to access it by other activities and use that variable in some MapView objects. It is a hard need for a "special" huge app

Comment: I am sorry, I still dont understand why that special need. Can you elaborate? If you only need information, passing the object is probably how I'd do it.